# How to generate all the values of an iterable besides the last few?

Tags: python

Say I have to define a function which takes in an iterable and generates all of the values except the last 5.  As of right now, I have something like this:

```
def generate_all_but_5(iterable):
    x = iter(iterable)
    list_of_current = []
    try:
        while True:
            list_of_current.append(next(x))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    for y in list_of_current[:-5]:
        yield y
```

This works, however I'm not allowed to copy all the values of the iterable into a list, like I did here, as there could be an infinite amount of values.  Is there another way to achieve the solution without adding everything to a list first?

Comment: If there could be infinite amount of values, how do you define which are the last five?

Comment: You could never recognise when you reached the fifth from end element because you never know when the end will come.

Answer (score 2):

I assume saving just 5 items in memory is fine. You can try this:

```
def generate_all_but_5(iterable):
    x = iter(iterable)
    list_of_current = []
    for i, item in enumerate(x):
        list_of_current.append(item)
        if i >= 5:
            yield list_of_current.pop(0)
```

It first loads 5 items from the iterable then pops and yields the front of the list and append the next. The last five will still be in `list_of_current` and won't be yield.

```
list(generate_all_but_5(range(6)))
# [0]
list(generate_all_but_5(range(10)))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
list(generate_all_but_5('Hello world!'))
# ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w']
```

Note that the side effect of this is that although the last 5 won't be returned from `generate_all_but_5`, but they'll still be pop out from the iterable passed in. Since you did not mention keeping the last 5 in the iterable untouched, I assume there's no such requirement.

**Explanation:**

Let's print `list_of_current` in the for loop to see what's going on.

```
def generate_all_but_5(iterable):
    x = iter(iterable)
    list_of_current = []
    for i, item in enumerate(x):
        print(list_of_current) # print the list
        list_of_current.append(item)
        if i >= 5:
            yield list_of_current.pop(0)

g = generate_all_but_5(range(8))
n = next(g)
# []
# [0]
# [0, 1]
# [0, 1, 2]
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# n = 0
n = next(g)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# n = 1
n = next(g)
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# n = 2
n = next(g)
# StopIteration Error
```

After the last yield, `list_of_current == [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. All of the last 5 items are in the list and there's no item left in the iterable.

I'm terrible at explaining things. I hope this example helps!

Comment: This was really helpful.  May I ask how this function knows to not print the last 5?  Wouldn't "i" continuously get bigger (e.g. 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, etc)?

Comment: @T.Li I've edited my answer with explanation. Hope it helps!

Comment: Rather than using `enumerate` you could just use `list_of_current` directly, and make the condition be `if len(list_of_current) > 5`. For that matter you probably should consider using a `queue` rather than a `list`, as it's better optimized for this sort of thing.

Comment: @DanielPryden Yeah I know that popping from the front and appending to the end each time coud be expansive, so using `queue` can for sure optimize it.